# Change Media Object (VBA PowerPoint)

Tags: vba, powerpoint, media

I just want to change the music of a Media Object in PowerPoint using Macros. I have a music in a Slide, but I can't figure out how I can change it to different music. Or is it possible to replace it by a new one but with the same properties...?
I tried playing around with following code but I don't know the rest...

```
Slide3.Shapes("bg_music").MediaFormat. 'code that I don't know to change it's music/media
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to delete the existing shape and replace it with a new one, copying the properties as needed. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg985317(v=office.14).aspx) enumerates some (all?) of the `MediaFormat` properties.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceMediaFormat()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim newShp As Shape
Dim shp As Shape
Dim mf As MediaFormat
Dim path As String

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) '// Modify as needed
Set shp = sld.Shapes("bg_music")
Set mf = shp.MediaFormat

'// Modify the path for your new media file:
path = "C:\Users\david.zemens\Downloads\2540.mp3"

Set newShp = sld.Shapes.AddMediaObject2(path)
With newShp
    .Top = shp.Top
    .Left = shp.Left
    .Width = shp.Width
    .Height = shp.Height
    ' etc...

End With

' // copy the mediaformat properties as needed

With newShp.MediaFormat
    .StartPoint = mf.StartPoint
    .EndPoint = mf.EndPoint
    .FadeInDuration = mf.FadeInDuration
    .FadeOutDuration = mf.FadeOutDuration
    .Muted = mf.Muted
    .Volume = mf.Volume
    ' etc...
End With

'// remove the original
shp.Delete

Dim eff As Effect
'// Creates an effect in the timeline which triggers this audio to play when the slideshow begins
Set eff = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(newShp, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)

With newShp.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings
    .LoopUntilStopped = msoCTrue
    .PauseAnimation = msoFalse
    .PlayOnEntry = msoCTrue
    .RewindMovie = msoCTrue
    .StopAfterSlides = 999
    .HideWhileNotPlaying = msoTrue
End With
```

With help from [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172814(v=office.11).aspx), I can get the audio to play automatically by creating an *effect* (see above `Set eff = ...`).

Comment: Ok thank you. But I'll need just one more thing, how to I change the "Background playing" to true (so that it plays in the background, in each slide)?

Comment: @DanielClímaco if you use the Locals window in the VBE to view the object properties, it looks like you can do that via `newShp.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings`.

Comment: I can't find the propertie "play between/through slides", that's the one I want (just forgot the name)

Comment: How do I enable the propertie to play through the slides?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see the end of your answer.

Comment: no problem, yes I added taht after you asked initially. I think you still need to click to get it to play initially, but once  playing it should continue through the slideshow.

Comment: @DavidZemens Is it possible to fade to a particular volume, rather than fade all the way to muted?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, this should be asked as a new question, not as a comment on an existing answer...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916028/fade-volume-of-background-media-on-specific-slide-in-powerpoint-using-vba